# Archos T101X 4G Android 10 : MediaScannerConnection.scanFile deletes my added file

Tags: java, android, file, storage, android-10.0

When I take a photo, I save the image in the DCIM / Camera folder in the external folder with this method:

**Method 1:**

```
File fImage = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + "/Camera/image.jpg");
ContentResolver resolver = activity.getContentResolver();
Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", fImage);
if(imageUri != null) {
    OutputStream fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);
    if(fos != null) {
        fos.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();        
        new SingleMediaScanner(activity, fImage);
     }
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
File fImage = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + "/Camera/image.jpg");
OutputStream outputStream=null;
try {
    outputStream=new FileOutputStream(fImage);
    outputStream.write(bytes);
}finally {
    if (outputStream != null)
         outputStream.close();
    new SingleMediaScanner(activity, fImage);
}
```

My file is present on the tablet in the desired folder.

My provider contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

In my manifest there is this:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="22"
    android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
...
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
<application
        ...
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true">
...
</application>
```

My class allowing the file scan:

```
public static class SingleMediaScanner implements MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient {

        private MediaScannerConnection mMs;
        private File mFile;

        public SingleMediaScanner(Context context, File f) {
            mFile = f;
            mMs = new MediaScannerConnection(context, this);
            mMs.connect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
            String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(mFile.getAbsolutePath()).toLowerCase();
            MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            String mimeType = mimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
            mMs.scanFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath(), mimeType);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            mMs.disconnect();
        }
}
```

After this scan, my created file is deleted. And the value of uri is null in onScanCompleted.

Do you know why ?

**Edited:**
I tested on a Samsung Tab A and there is no problem. But on an Archos T101X4G it doesn't work.

Comment: @blackapps I added the line of the missing mediascanner call in the function.

Comment: `if(fos != null)` And if fos==null you could display a Toast so the user knows that something went wrong.

Comment: @blackapps yes but in my case there is no problem, the file is indeed created on the tablet. I see it by connecting the tablet to the pc. But if I call SingleMediaScanner the file disappears.

Comment: @blackapps I add the line : new SingleMediaScanner(activity, fImage);

Comment: Tested. It does not happen here. Nice uri obtained.

Comment: @blackapps I just tested on a samsung and there is no problem. In fact the problem is on an Archos T101X4G.

Comment: Try following code for the Archos: `Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
sendBroadcast(intent);`

Comment: @blackapps Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE is deprecated on Android 10, so the scan is not performed on the archos. And therefore file not visible when connecting to a pc.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I think that the problem comes only from the tablet Archos: I just tested with WhatsApp and an image downloaded in WhatsApp also disappears...